# Absolute value inside an absolute value inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Let the inequality equation be,

$||x|-5|<|x-6|$, the solution set for this I found to be $(-∞, 5.5) \cup (5.5, ∞)$

I got four different equations and two of them were no solutions, would this be a correct way to present the solution set?  That is, should I have ended up with 4 equations?  I'm very positive the algebra is correct but feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I believe it is just $x < 5.5$.

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting $||x|-5|<|x-6|$, we see there are five intervals of interest:
\begin{align*}&x > 6\\6 > &x > 5\\ 5 > &x > 0\\ 0 > &x > -5\\ -5 > &x\end{align*}
Before working with these, we can see that the inequality clearly holds for $x=-5, x= 0, x = 5$, but it does not hold for $x = 6$.

For $x > 6$, $||x|-5|<|x-6| \Leftrightarrow x - 5 < x - 6$, which is impossible.
For $-5 < x < 5$, $||x|-5|<|x-6| \Leftrightarrow 5 - |x| < 6 - x$, which is clearly true.
For $x < -5$, $||x|-5|<|x-6| \Leftrightarrow |x|-5 < 6 - x \Leftrightarrow |x|+x < 11$, which is clearly true as $|x|+x = 0$ for negative $x$.

Therefore we have established that $(-\infty, 5]$ is a subset of the solution set, and $[6, \infty)$ is a subset of the non-solution set. All that remains is the case where $5<x<6$.

If $5<x<6$, then $||x|-5|<|x-6| \Leftrightarrow x-5 < 6 - x \Leftrightarrow x+x < 11$. This holds when $x<5.5$. Hence we also know that $(5, 5.5)$ is part of the solution set, while $[5.5, 6)$ is not.

Therefore the set of solutions is $(-\infty, 5.5)$

To verify that this is truly all of the solutions, note that $\mathbb{R} = (–\infty, 5.5)\cup[5.5, \infty)$ where the first set has been shown to be consistent with the equation, and the second set has been shown to be inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can go step by step and use that (for $a>0$):

$$|y|<a\to -a<y<a  \\|y|>a \to y<-a \text { or } y>a$$

So,

$$||x|-5|<|x-6|\to -|x-6|<|x|-5<|x-6|\to 5-|x-6|<|x|<5+|x-6|$$

$1.$ For the first case:

$$|x|<5+|x-6|\to -(5+|x-6|)<x<5+|x-6|$$

$1.1$ $$-(5+|x-6|)<x\to |x-6|>-x-5$$

so we have two cases:
$$x-6<-(-x-5)\to-6<5 \to x\in \Bbb R$$

$$x-6>-x-5\to x>0.5$$

combining those two cases we get $x\in \Bbb R \quad (1)$

$1.2$

$$x<5+|x-6|\to |x-6|>x-5$$

again we have two cases:

$$x-6<-(x-5)\to x<5.5$$
$$x-6>x-5\to \text{ no solution}$$

combining those two cases we get $x< 5.5 \quad (2)$

Finally, from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $x<5.5$.

I will let the second case for you.